# CryptoStream: Length of the data to decrypt is invalid. Same code does not generate error on same data

Tags: c#, encryption, des

Okay, this weird, to me.  I have this code, which works:

```
using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(inBytes))
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(memStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
{
    byte[] buffer;
    if (inBytes.Length < (1024 * 10)) buffer = new byte[inBytes.Length];
    else buffer = new byte[(1024 * 10)];
    long readBytes = 0;
    long totalBytes = inStream.Length;
    int currBytes;

    while (readBytes < totalBytes)
    {
        currBytes = cs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        fs.Write(buffer, 0, currBytes);
        readBytes += currBytes;
    }
}
```

This writes decrypted data out to a file.

Then I have this code which does exactly the same thing, except it writes to (and returns) a `MemoryStream`:

```
using(MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(inBytes))
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(memStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
{
    byte[] buffer;
    if (inBytes.Length < (1024 * 10)) buffer = new byte[inBytes.Length];
    else buffer = new byte[(1024 * 10)];
    long readBytes = 0;
    long totalBytes = inStream.Length;
    int currBytes;

    while (readBytes < totalBytes)
    {
        currBytes = cs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        ms.Write(buffer, 0, currBytes);
        readBytes += currBytes;
    }

    return ms;
}
```

On the line `currBytes = cs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)` I receive the error "Length of the data to decrypt is invalid" but only on the second set, not the first.  The `ICryptoTransform` "decryptor" is created from a common method, and I know it's using the same key.

Can anyone tell me why I would not be getting this error in the first instance, but would be in the second, and (more importantly) how to fix it.

And, yes, I know DES is not the best encryption method ever.  This is something in the nature of a proof-of-concept that will never see the light of day in a production environment.

Comment: Stupid question maybe, but are you 100% sure that the input (inBytes) is the same in both cases?

Comment: Yes.  I actually made changes to my calling code to ensure this 100% (It should have been anyway, but I went ahead and removed any doubt).

Comment: Where is `inStream` defined? Should this line: `long totalBytes = inStream.Length;` be `long totalBytes = memStream.Length;`?

Comment: I've seen this, but only when trying to decrypt data that was encrypted with a different key.

Comment: `inStream` is part of the method signature.  It gets converted to a byte[] (inBytes) (in part to deal with this issue, actually, I was trying to ensure I had the same number of bytes in both methods- I do)

Comment: Right. And when it happens, are we in a `1024 * 10` or in a `inBytes.Length` scenario?

Comment: @Henk Holterman: inBytes.Length.

Comment: What happens if you get rid of `readBytes` and `totalBytes` altogether and replace your `while` loop with something like this instead? `int currBytes; while ((currBytes = cs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) { ms.Write(buffer, 0, currBytes); }`

Comment: As a note, to fix a separate problem I'd been having, I converted my DES Padding to `Padding.None`.  I have commented out that line to control for that (allowing the decryptor to use the default padding) with no change.

Comment: What value is `decryptor.CanReuseTransform` and are you reusing it? (it's quite clear the problem is not in the code you posted).

Comment: @Henk Holterman: I'm using the default, there.  No, I'm not reusing it.  I re-initialize the decryptor each time I decrypt.

Comment: Insert some log statements in both sets to show inBytes.Length and maybe the first and last couple of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error today and it turned out that I had converted one source string into a byte array using ASCII in one function and the other using Base64 in a different function.

It may be that although your inputs are of the correct length they are not using the same encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add these checks to both pieces of code. I strongly suspect one or both of these fails:

```
if ( inStream.Length != inBytes.Length )
  throw new Exception("inBytes read incorrectly");
if ( inBytes.Length % 8 == 0 )
  throw new Exception("inBytes is not a valid DES encryption");
```